# Error while configuring PhpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

I have installed phyMyAdmin on my Ubuntu 12.04 using sudo apt-get..
I configured the Apache2 Server as it was given in the Documentation
The problem I am facing is that when i take `http://localhost/phyMyAdmin`  nothing is displayed in the browser,instead it downloads a php file.
Why is this occuring?How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing **PHP**.

**From the terminal:**

`sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql`

**Then restart Apache:**

`sudo service apache2 restart`

You can then navigate to `http://localhost/phyMyAdmin` and it'll work.